# Переключение между окнами

Tags: java, javafx

Я только начал изучать *JavaFX*.

Моя задача: создать экспертную систему, с вариантами ответов только **Да** или **Нет** (кнопки).

Я создаю форму `sample.fxml`, через `SceneBuilder`. Выставил все, что мне нужно.
Также создал `Window2.fxml`.

Теперь, как мне вызвать `sample.fxml` и по нажатию кнопки **Да**, форма `sample.fxml` закрывалась, а открывалась `Window2.fxml`, но если же нажимается кнопка **Нет**, то соответственно открывается другая форма?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здравствуйте.Итак по пунктам:

1. > Теперь, как мне вызвать sample.fxml

В главном классе:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

    stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

2. > нажатию кнопки Да, форма sample.fxml закрывалась, а открывалась
   >   Window2.fxml

В контроллере FXMLController, закрываем главную форму и открываем другую, модальную:

```
@FXML private javafx.scene.control.Button button;

@FXML private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    //Close current
    Stage stage = (Stage) button.getScene().getWindow();
    // do what you have to do
    stage.close();
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Window2.fxml"));
    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.setTitle("Другая форма");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
    stage.show();
}
```

3. > но если же нажимается кнопка Нет, то соответственно открывается другая
   >   форма:

В контроллере FXMLController, открываем другую, модальную (Обратите внимание что главная форма не закрывается, поскольку Вы описали задачу именно так):

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonActionAnotherForm(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");

    /*
        //Close current
        Stage stage = (Stage) button.getScene().getWindow();
        // do what you have to do
        stage.close();
     */
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/anotherForm.fxml"));
    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.setTitle("Вообще другая форма");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
    stage.show();

}
```

На всякий случай даю ссылку на готовый maven-проект:
[mvnFX](https://331520@bitbucket.org/331520/jfxmv.git)

**PS:** Решения честно тырил тут :) :

[Открытие нового модального окна](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160951/javafx-open-another-fxml-in-the-another-window-with-button)

[Закрытие текущего окна](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567019/close-fxml-window-by-code-javafx)

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! Именно то, что нужно!